# Where in stored procedure I can make exit status?

Tags: oracle

I have oracle stored procedure where i check sender I'd,source system, and transaction number at the beginning of the procedure. Can I do it this way:

```
 If Id != "aaa"    
      Exit -1;    
 Else if source = " ".   
      Exit -1;    
 Else if trans = " ".   
      Exit -1;    
 Else.   
     -- continues stored procedure
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Just do a `return;` to exit a procedure.

Comment: Oracle is using return statement in sub program, after which control goes to the caller, I.e. From function to stored procedure. Probably I have to use exception.

Answer (score 2):

To rephrase your question more generally, you want a caller of your routine to know if something bad has happened inside it. There are (at least) three ways of doing this in PL/SQL.

### Use an `OUT` parameter

Procedure cannot *return* a value, the way a function does, but it can set an output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inner (p_id IN VARCHAR2(10), p_res OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  p_res := 0; -- default value
  IF p_id = 'aaa' THEN
    p_res := -1;
    RETURN;
  ELSE
    -- do something 
  END IF;
END;
```

Then in the caller you would have:

```
DECLARE res NUMBER;
...
inner('aaa', res);
IF res = -1 THEN
  -- panic!
END IF;
...
```

### Use a function

Despite your seeming aversion to functions, this might be an option.

```
CREATE FUNCTION inner (p_id IN VARCHAR2(10))
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  IF p_id = 'aaa' THEN
    RETURN -1;
  END IF;
  -- do something 
  RETURN 0;
END;
```

Then in the caller:

```
...
IF inner('aaa') = -1 THEN
  -- panic!
END IF;
...
```

### Use an exception

Similar to other programming languages, PL/SQL has exceptions:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE inner (p_id IN VARCHAR2(10))
IS
BEGIN
  IF p_id = 'aaa' THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'ID cannot be ''aaa''');
  ELSE
    -- do something 
  END IF;
END;
```

and in the caller:

```
...
DECLARE
  panic  EXCEPTION;                       -- declare exception
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (panic, -20000);  -- assign error code to exception
...
BEGIN
  inner ('aaa');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN panic THEN
    -- proceed to panic
END;
```

Comment: When we use pragma, can we exit with some status?

Comment: Exit to where? Your routine executes deep in the bowel of the database server, and what "exit" means depends on the interface that you use to call the procedure.

Comment: I made a java program, which calls stored procedure and I return -1 to java program, which will do something in this case. Return oracle doesn't,t use. So I want to exit and java will check exit status

Comment: If you call using JDBC your routine and don't handle the exception in PL/SQL, it will cause a `java.sql.SQLException`, which you can handle in your Java program.

Comment: It is not sqlexception. It is no values in three parameters of stored procedure

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. If you call `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR()` in your PL/SQL routine and don't handle it there, it will be propagated back to the JDBC driver, which will roll back the transaction and throw an `SQLException`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong syntax both for the `IF...ELSE` and for the `exit`.

Given that you are saying you need to get a return value, you probably need a function like this, using `CASE`:

```
create or replace function testFun ( pIn1 varchar2, pIn2 varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
    case 
      when pIn1 is null then
        return -1;
      when pIn2 = ' ' then
       return -2; 
      else
        return 999;
    end case;
end;
```